# Is it normal that the strange src addr appears when DMA(PLX PEX 8733) runs a while?

Tags: memory, linux-device-driver, dma, pci-e

I am curious about the processing of DMA(PEX 8733) driver transfer, and using kzalloc to get a piece of buff for observing a running DMA descriptor table.

It is according to DMA spec, the descriptor format is like:
[descriptor format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaIPh.png)

When I start my observation, the result is like [expected example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXJzx.png)
(The order is dw0, dw1, dw2, dw3.) or expected example 2.

**expected example 2:**

```
DMA Descriptor Entry 0, (80003c66, 3890, 74ea046c, fff4028e)
DMA Descriptor Entry 1, (c000042e, 3890, 74ea0048, fff4024e)
```

After a while(about 2 hours), the result shows: [unexpected example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX27l.png) or unexpected example 2

**unexpected example 2:**

```
DMA Descriptor Entry 0, (80007c0e, ffff3890, 65da046e, fffc04ee)
DMA Descriptor Entry 1, (c000042e, ffff3890, 65da0040, fffc00c0)
```

I am not able to realize the dw1 have `0xffff` in source address' high byte.

Do I misunderstand or miss something about DMA descriptor?

I am not sure the potential issue(Additional messages) which is related to the high src addr, but it appears when DMA runs a while.

**Additional messages:**

```
DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 402
DMAR: DMAR: [DMA Read] Request device [01:00.2] fault addr fffc0000
DMAR: [fault reason 06] PTE Read access is not set
```

Comment: I cannot follow your results. You say the observations are in dw0,1,2,3 order, but in your "expected" output, dw0 is always 0, which would mean (according to the format spec you link to) the transfer size is 0 and the descriptor valid bit is never set.  What am I missing?

Comment: Also, it's *much* more convenient for readers if you can paste text into your question rather than provide links to images of the text.

Comment: Thanks @GilHamilton  reply and suggestion.

Comment: @GilHamilton Yes ,the entries are actually invalid and 0 transfer size in example 1. I find the expected and unexpected example 1 are not good. Thus, I add the example 2 with a clear way to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: With your latest examples, I'd say you're interpreting the descriptor correctly. The high bytes of the source address *are* `ffff` in your unexpected entries. That seems likely to be incorrect (it's theoretically possible but that's a very high memory address). So how it got that way is the issue. I doubt that anyone will be able to help you here without much more detailed info.

Comment: @GilHamilton I guess I am able to try `CONFIG_ARCH_DMA_ADDR_T_64BIT=n` to observe whether the high byte appears.